# relation between algebraic multiplicity and diagonalization

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Suppose $\lambda_0$ be an eigenvalue of $A$ with algebraic multiplicity $k$; If $k>\dim Null(A-\lambda_0 I)$, then $A$ is not diagonalizable. is this statement true or false? could anyone help me to solve?

Comment: Yes, it's true. The criterion is that the characteristic polynomial splits as product of linear factors, and that, for all eigenvalues, the geometric multiplicity be equal to the algebraic multiplicity.

Comment: no it is not to be diagonalizable $k$ must be equal to $dim Null(A-\lambda_0 I)$ but you can still simplify $A$ by transforming it into a triangular matrix 
see this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Triangularisability

Comment: @1.2.3 Your comment is very unclear: are you trying to tell the OP the statement he wrote there is *not* true? Because it is, so I think you should have written something like "Yes, it is. For $\;A\;$ to be diagonalizable it must be $\;k=\dim\ker (A-\lambda_0I)(\;$ ...and etc." . Also, not writing periods, commas and stuff like this makes things unclear and can even change meanings, some times.